# CreatedAt property null when working with Offline tables in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, offline, azure-mobile-services

This is a basic example to show the issue.

I have a MobileServiceClient and offline SyncTable

```
private MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("http://localhost:19087/");
private IMobileServiceSyncTable<TodoItem> todoTable;
```

I have a TodDoItem.cs on the client

```
 public class TodoItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }       
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}
```

I initialise my offline Database like so

```
async Task Initialise()
    {
        if (!client.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
        {
            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("todo.db");
            store.DefineTable<TodoItem>();
            await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());
        }
        todoTable = client.GetSyncTable<TodoItem>();
    }
```

and sync online data with offline here

```
async Task RefreshData()
    {
        await todoTable.PullAsync("todo", null);
        var result = await todoTable.ToCollectionAsync();
        listItems.ItemsSource = result;
    }
```

Now the problem here is the CreatedAt property is always null. If I make the property non nullable then it shows as date 01/01/0001 (basically DateTime.Min). The record in the DB has the correct date. Testing with fiddler shows the correct date is being serialized ok from the MobileService

If I change to an online environment ie

```
private IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable;
```

then everything works as expected. CreatedAt is showing the correct date.
I have tried a JsonConverter as shown by [Carlos' fix here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/05/13/preserving-date-time-offsets-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx) but that doesnt work as the date is already 01/01/0001 (wrong) as it enters the converter.
I really need to order records by date and cant figure out why this isnt working in the offline environment. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default system properties (createdAt, version, updatedAt, etc) are not pulled down in a query.  Updating your definition like so will have it ask for the column from the server and know what value to put it into.

```
 public class TodoItem
 {
  public string Id { get; set; }       
  [CreatedAt]
  public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
  [UpdatedAt]
  public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public bool Complete { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Still getting this error with the Annotations. Its wierd because this actually helps, but, I can still replicate the bug *sometimes*. Double checked my code, I never set theses properties to null.

Comment: Update. My error happens when adding a new record. I have a list of old items which are correct. If I add to this list a new item (where I manually set the DateTime anyways), and push the changes, then re-poll from the services table the value is null.

Comment: The local value of those columns is not sent to the server / respected by it.  The local column would be replaced by what the server returns from the POST to the table.  If you POST to /tables/todo?__includeSystemPropeties=* does your response have the __createdAt column in it with a value?

Comment: I can understand the server overriding my values. I cant understand the server overriding my values with null after I push.

Comment: Right, but to help narrow down the problem, what does your server return when you do a POST?  Is it returning the correct values for __createdAt and __updatedAt?